# iCloud and Xcode 6 - Ubiquity Container

Tags: icloud, code-signing, xcode6, entitlements, cloudkit

I am currently working on an app for iOS 8 which uses iCloud Drive and the CloudKit Framework. 
Everything was set up by using Xcode 6.

When I try to submit my App to iTunesConnect I get the following error: 
[image]

When I'm adding the Key in my iCloud entitlements I'm not able to Code sign the app and Xcode sends me an error,too.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
<string>de.sn0wfreeze.CloudFInder</string>
```

I'll get that error:

[image]

And I'm not able to Code sign. Can anyone please help my with that issue ?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue.  Xcode wants to create **'icloud'** entitlements, but not **'ubiquity'** type entitlements. In fact giving you an error if you manually create them in the entitlement file as you explained.  
I am able to upload / submit an app if take what xCode provides in the 'capabilities' section of the project settings, and add manually the `'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers'`

This results in an error within XCode, but allows me to submit the app.

This must be a bug in xcode, if it's user error I would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same situation. After stumbling around for a while, this is what seemed to work:

1. In the online developer.apple.com member center, I turned off cloud entitlement in the app id. Then turned it back on. And selected "Cloud Kit" (not Xcode 5 compatibility). Then I regenerated my provisioning profile and downloaded and installed it.
2. In Xcode 6.0.1, under Capabilities, I left key-value storage selected, and selected CloudKit (iCloud Documents *not* selected; I don't use it). "Use default container" was selected, and that was the same as given in the app id on the online member center.

Good luck!