# Missing Ubiquity Entitlement

Tags: app-store-connect, icloud, provisioning-profile

I am not able to validate the archive for my app due to a missing ubiquity entitlement to go along with the iCloudDocuments entitlement (see attached image).

I have configured the iCloud entitlements in the capabilities section in Xcode 6 in standard fashion as shown.

Things I've tried to solve this issue:
1. Deleting and recreating my distribution profile
2. Disabling/Enabling iCloud capability both in Xcode and in the member center
3. Using a custom ubiquity container instead of the default.
4. Disassociating/re-associating the different containers with my app.
5. Restarting Xcode
6. Cleaning the project

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of "iCloud and Xcode 6 - Ubiquity Container": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886250/icloud-and-xcode-6-ubiquity-container

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having exactly the same problems and can't seem to resolve.

Comment: I resolved the problem and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. This appears to be the result of a bug in Xcode. Here are the steps I took:

1. In my Target -> Capabilities tab I used a custom ubiquity container rather than the default. In my case, I simply used the container id that was the default but manually entered it as a custom container id.
2. Under the entitlements file I added the entitlement `Ubiquity Container Identifiers` and entered in my container id as item 0.
3. Under the entitlements file I manually entered in my ubiquity container id as item 0.